# linkedIN profileAPI data extract

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am in the process of collecting a huge data set for a new project. Let me brief a little about our research work so far.

Microsoft Academic search contains details of the papers published in a conference or journal. 
Using their API, I will get the list of papers published in a certain conference. From the same Microsoft Academic search API, I will get more details of the paper such as title, abstract, author, organization (Where the author works) etc. To get a huge data set, we decided on getting more information about the author (some more details that will be present in his linkedin profile). To get the details, we decided to use profile API of linkedin. However, I read in an article that linkedin doesn't allow data extraction for research purposes. It was answered by a linkedin employee in the below link.

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-get-public-profile-url-members-linked-api

My question is,

Is there any other way to get more information about an author apart from linkedin?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one workaround:

1. Auhtenticate your own linkedin profile with your own application
2. Conduct a linkedin API search to find the person you need.
3. Send a message to that person via the API, detailing what you are doing, and asking them to authenticate on your website via their linkedin profile
4. Once they have authenticated, you will be able to save their profile data, in a perfectly legal way, since they would have given you the authorization to do so.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Samer,                                                       Thanks a lot for replying. Actually, I won't be knowing the list of people whose details I want to collect. The author/people list will be returned by Microsoft Academic search API. I have to get more details of that particular author using linkedin API. If my api returns around 10000 author names, it is not a good idea to send 10000 authorization requests. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: That's the only way you can do it. After you search via MS API, you will need to use the information you got from there in order to conduct a linkedin search API. The only legal way where you could store the author's data on your website is to ask them to authorize themselves to your app, in order to be able to link their publications to their linkedin profile information. Any other method will risk blocking your application from using Linkedin API.